# Best way extract gameId from array object

Tags: javascript

I have a 2D array `matches` where I store the game id and another array of objects `games` where I store `gameId` with the `playerId`.

Here is what I have done so far:

Step 1: I get the opponent's gameId against the gameId from "matches" array.

e.g. gameId "2" has an opponent "1"

Step 2: check opponent_game in games and return game.

```js
    let gameId = 2
    
    let matches = [
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4]
    ]
    
    const opponent_game = matches.filter((v, i) => {
        if (v.includes(gameId)) {
            var index = v.indexOf(gameId);
            if (index > -1) {
                return v.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    })
    
    let games = [{
        gameId: 1,
        playerId: 222
    }, {
        gameId: 4,
        playerId: 222
    }]
    
    const game = games.filter((v, i) => {
        return v.gameId === opponent_game[0][0] 
    })
    
    console.log(game)
```

Please suggest best practices in javascript or an optimized and clean way to write the same solution. TIA

Comment: Does this code work? The `matches.filter` call looks wrong. The callback function should return a boolean, but you are returning an array or `undefined` .

Comment: yes it's working

Answer (score 1):

`.includes()` and checking `.indexOf()` against `-1` do the same thing, you only need one.

Also the function should be returning a boolean value. It currently works because the array returned by `.splice()` is considered `true` and not returning anything (or `undefined`) is considered `false`. It would be better to explicitly return a boolean:

```
 const opponent_game = matches.filter((v, i) => {
    var index = v.indexOf(gameId);
    if (index > -1) {
        v.splice(index, 1);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
})
```

However modifying the content of an array in a `filter` is bad practice, because it is unexpected. Since you only looking for a single value `.reduce()` would probably be the better choice:

```
 const opponent_game = matches.reduce((acc, v) => {
    if (acc !== null) {
      return acc;
    }
    var index = v.indexOf(gameId);
    if (index > -1) {
        return v[1 - index];
    }
    return null;
}, null)
```

In this case `opponent_game` is a number and no longer an array containing an array containing a number so that simplifies the second part too. Also since you are looking for a single item `.find()` would be more appropriate:

```
const game = games.find(v => {
    return v.gameId === opponent_game
})
```

Comment: have run this code? console.log(opponent_game) return result "2"

Comment: @ManjeetThakur Fixed it. I shouldn't have used `splice` in the reduce version.

Comment: I'm still not satisfied and also try another way to solve this problem